# SMTP Using Authentication Email as From Address

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm using basic SMTP settings on a client website for email handling. I'm currently using Google's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) on port 587, currently using my personal gmail credentials to authenticate. I don't know if this matters, but I'm using TLS encryption as well.

I've set a "From Address" so that emails sent are from a particular email. Yet, when emails are sent out, it uses my personal email from the authentication.

This is a Wordpress site with a MySQL database, if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: Why the email would be sent with my authentication email as the from address as opposed to the actual from address I set.

Comment: And the answer is... ;-) because of the gmail server configuration. You are authenticating with one address and if you want to send email as someone else you should add aliass via gmail account.

Comment: Got it. Thank you both. I decided to use a different SMTP server actually (Mandrill) which should circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use that setup, but I had a similar problem using the gmail client. There is a good chance the root cause is the same.

Basically Google is skeptical about why you are saying you are someone other than the person with the account. You can overcome this with some extra configuration in your gmail settings. They have a help article describing what you need to do.

[Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)